# Convert 2 columns of a pandas dataframe to a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I know that you can pull out a single column from a datframe to a list by doing this:

```
newList = df['column1'].tolist()
```

and that you can convert all values to a list like this:

```
newList = df.values.tolist()
```

But is there a way to convert 2 columns from a dataframe to a list so that you get a list that looks like this

```
    Column 1    Column 2 
0     apple      9
1     peach      12
```

and the resulting list is:

```
[[apple,9],[peach,12]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `newList = df[['column1', 'column2']].tolist()` or maybe `newList = df.loc[:, ['column1', 'column2']].tolist()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your example, you can convert a pandas DataFrame to a list with `df.values.tolist()`.

If you want just specific columns, you just need to change df in this code to df containing only those columns, as `df[[column1, column2, ..., columnN]].values.tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip:

```
[list(i) for i in zip(df['Column 1'], df['Column 2'])]
```

Output

```
[[apple,9],[peach,12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the entire data frame to a list of lists:

```
lst = df.to_numpy().tolist()
```